# Event propagation and multiple state change in react select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
    import React from "react";

    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        companies: [
          {
            name: "company1",
            jobs: [
              {
                name: "job1-1",
                salary: [{ junior: 1234 }, { senior: 2345 }, { mid: 34566 }]
              },
              {
                name: "job1-2",
                salary: [
                  {
                    junior: 9876
                  },
                  {
                    senior: 98777
                  },
                  {
                    mid: 34566
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "job1-3",
                salary: [
                  {
                    junior: 9446
                  },
                  {
                    senior: 98947
                  },
                  {
                    mid: 134566
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "company2",
            jobs: [
              {
                name: "job2-1",
                salary: [
                  { junior: 343431234 },
                  { senior: 552345 },
                  { mid: 4434566 }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "job2-2",
                salary: [
                  {
                    junior: 99876
                  },
                  {
                    senior: 5698777
                  },
                  {
                    mid: 4434566
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "job3-3",
                salary: [
                  {
                    junior: 933446
                  },
                  {
                    senior: 9338947
                  },
                  {
                    mid: 13334566
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        selectedCompany: "company1",
        selectedJob: "job1-1"
      };

      handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ selectedCompany: e.target.value });
      };

      handleChange2 = e => {
        this.setState({ selectedJob: e.target.value });
      };

      render = () => {
        let company = this.state.companies.filter(company => {
          return company.name === this.state.selectedCompany;
        });


        return (
          <div>
            jobs
            <select
              value={this.state.selectedJob}
              onChange={this.handleChange2.bind(this)}
            >
              {company[0].jobs.map((sal, i) => {
                return <option>{sal.name}</option>;
              })}
            </select>
            companies
            <select
              value={this.state.selectedCompany}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            >
              {this.state.companies.map((company, i) => {
                return <option>{company.name}</option>;
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        );
      };
    }

    export default App;
```

What I have done is, there are 3 nested arrays inside the `companies` array. `jobs` inside `companies` and `salary` inside `job`. The output looks like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD9X3.png)

The onChange handler of `Company` works, it also changes the initial state of `selectedCompany` to whichever I select using the handleChange event. The onChange triggers the `Jobs` to change according to the selected Company.

Now, the question is how do I change the initial state of selectedJob too? I have made another handleChange2 for Job. If I explicitely select job, the selectedJob changes it's value but I need to make it work Just by the change in Company.

The react developer tool shows that `selectedJob` value changes only if I manually select one.

In summary, change the state of `selectedJob` by changing the state of Company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your query correctly, then you want on change of `company`, the first job from the selected company should get set as `selectedJob` in state.

You can do like this,

```
handleChange = e => {
  let company = this.state.companies.filter(company => {
    return company.name === e.target.value;
  });

  let selectedJob = company[0].jobs[0].name;  //This will get first job from selected company

  this.setState({ selectedCompany: e.target.value, selectedJob }, ()=> console.log(this.state.selectedJob));
  };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8kfajz)

**Note:** You need to add `key` when you iterate `array` using `.map`. See the warning you are getting and `key` accordingly.

Comment: Lastly, how do I add null value to the select dropdown sir?

Comment: null value means, you want something like select option should be shown?

Comment: You should add `<option>Select</option>` before map.

Comment: meaning, if i select company1 then the job dropdown should have "all" option so that i can get salary of all jobs as output. Let's say all option instead of null.

Comment: You should add `<option>All</option>` before map

Comment: I did what you said but throws error saying  `Cannot read property 'level' of undefined`. Please have a look. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tyt1nu

Comment: I guess i figured it out. I have condition if only the selected state is not "all" based on that the state changes. thanks anyway.